# What program can print source code well on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, printing, utilities

I am looking for an OS X application to nicely format and print source code from a variety of programming languages.

- Line numbers would be nice
- Constant width font
- Printing the contents of the clipboard would be a real plus

Does something like this exist (besides the obvious programmers' editors), free or reasonably priced?

Comment: Why is it a big deal to print the contents of the clipboard? Just save as a temporary file. In any case some formatters need the file extension to infer the language

Comment: Do you want recognition of keywords, strings, constants, comments? Bold, italic? Colors? Configurable colors? PS output? PDF output? Configurable font size? Headers/footers? Duplex and n-up printing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will find a nice answer over at sister site [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/362882/how-can-i-print-source-code-on-os-x-with-line-numbers). It involves a terminal program called [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) which comes with lot's of options and I know at least of one support file for extending its capabilities to print Ruby code.

EDIT:

I just noticed the "clipboard" part of the question. The clipboard content can be accessed from the command line and fed to `enscript` using `pbpaste` as mentioned in Matteo answer.

Comment: Presumably you need to find and install this, because it's not in my path on OS X.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use the terminal for this task and want a mac 'application' you should look at '[Text Wrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)' by Bare Bones Software. It is freeware, which fits your 'low price' request ;)

I use it to print out smaller runs of text, and use it specifically for the line number feature.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with the command line you could use a2ps (free and open source) which can be installed via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (install MacPorts and then `sudo port install a2ps`) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (install Homebrew and then `brew install a2ps`).

For example:

```
a2ps -1 --line-numbers=5 -g source.c
```

will print `source.c` with syntax highlighting (`-g`) and line numbers each 5 pages. See the [manual page](http://www.inf.enst.fr/%7Edemaille/a2ps/doc-4.12/a2ps_toc.html) for additional options. It supports a wide variety of source formats.

To print the content of the clipboard:

```
pbpaste | a2ps -1 --line-numbers=5
```

`pbpaste` prints the content of the clipboard to standard output which is read by a2ps.

Comment: If open source apps dont work for you, I recommend TextMate from http://macromates.com

Comment: You can also get a2ps from Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).  Some people like it better than MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

See also [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/), which supports many input languages and several output formats.

Answer (score 1):

Do it online on https://carbon.now.sh/ or on https://github.com/jaredpetersen/codeprinter. The latter can be run locally too.